# Not able to configure Moxy using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, moxy

I am using Moxy Implementation of JAXB in my codeset and trying to create paths using @XMLPath but it seems to be not working. I have a Spring bassed Project and I have created jaxb.properties under /project/WEB/src/main/resources having content :

javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

My classes are placed under /project/WEB/src/main/java
I have configured my pom.xml to download the dependancy.
persistence.moxy -->

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run the code on WAS server, Moxy is not recongnized and the path is not created. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

I even tried testing my JAXBContext class but what I get on the console is :

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DocGenerator.class); 
System.out.println(jaxbContext.getClass());
```

class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 5):

In case this helps anyone else, the following fixed my recent "MOXy is configured but is being ignored" problem.

I tested it on Java 11 (Open JDK) by implementing the first example shown in the [@XmlPath](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.7/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/annotations/XmlPath.html) Javadoc.

In line with the instructions [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/SpecifyRuntime), I added the required properties file to the package containing my domain classes (the annotated beans which I wanted to serialize).

### Solution for my IDE

The step I initially forgot to do was this:

My IDE only copies compiled `.class` files to the target directory - it does not copy anything else (such as my properties file).

Duh.

How you fix that depends on your IDE. For me, it was a simple change to the ant build configuration for my project.

If you are using Maven, then the build step in the `pom.xml` would be as follows:

```xml
<build>  
    <resources>  
        <resource>  
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>  
            <excludes>  
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>  
            </excludes>  
        </resource>  
    </resources>  
</build>
```

### Solution for the JAR

Similarly, Maven needs to be instructed to copy the file to that folder in your JAR.  There are various ways to do this.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372374/move-a-text-file-into-target-folder-when-compiling-a-maven-project) for some answers.

### Resources Directory

Placing this specific config file into a `resources` directory does ***not*** work (at least, it did not work for me). The MOXy instructions are quite specific - and need to be followed exactly.

### POM Dependencies

In Java 11, the module java.se.ee has been removed. See [JEP-320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320). This module includes JAXB (and JAX-WS). To use JAXB in Java 11 and newer, you need to add it to your project as a separate library.

Given that, here are my POM dependencies, for the record:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- 
             Use 2.3.1 below to prevent "illegal 
             reflective access operation" warnings.
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

---

### **UPDATES** for MOXy version 3

The above notes work for MOXy version 2.7.6.

To work with version 3+, you need to take into account the recent transfer of many `javax` packages to Jakarta. You can read the background to this move [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee).

Steps to upgrade your project:

1. Change the `jaxb.properties` file to the following:

```
jakarta.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Note the changed reference to `jakarta` here, for the bind context.

2. Change **all** of your jaxb imports to refer to `jakarta` instead of `javax`. So, for example, change this:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext; // old import
```

to this:

```java
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext; // new import
```

3. Use the following two dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

These two dependencies are sufficient to support an updated version of the code example presented here: [XPath Based Mapping using MOXy](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html).

Comment: I am trying to make `@XmlPath` work. I have a maven project and I have all the maven dependency as you have but an updated version. I have the properties file within the `package` of the `class` which I am using in `JAXBContext` for `JAX searlization`. Seems like everything is fine from my side but still the `@XmlPath` has no impact on the produced XML file. With or without `@XmlPath` it's producing the same result. I have maven dependency so do I have to again add the `JAR` to my classpath? I am using `IntelliJ IDE` how can I make iDE take the properties file?

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 - have you checked to see which JAXB implementation is being used by your application? You can use the code in the question to do that: `JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YourClassNameGoesHere.class);` And then `System.out.println(jaxbContext.getClass());`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks a lot for your response. Yes I did check that. it shows me `class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl`. I have posted my question here completely, if you get a chance please have a look and provide your solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500565/xmlpath-has-no-impact-during-the-jaxb-marshalling

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 - OK - that's the Metro implementation - not MOXy. So yes, there is a config problem somewhere. If I can I will take a look at your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me. This should work unless there is some conflict due to another dependency which I was having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500565/xmlpath-has-no-impact-during-the-jaxb-marshalling